# Sharing data between two processes with ProcessPoolExecutor

Tags: python, database, redis, process

I'm trying to share data between two processes. I have two classes `classA` and `classB`. The `classA` uses `ProcessPoolExecutor` to execute a function in `classA`. Since ProcessPoolExecutor does not allow pickling dictionaries, I used `redis` to share memory and the data between the `classA` and `classB`.

I use the following code to save data in `classB`.

```
self.redisClient.hmset("person1-hash", {
                "name": "jane",
                "age": 20
            })
```

In the `classA`, I'm checking if the `key` person1-hash is present. If so,I'm trying to retrieve the data.

```
if self.redisClient.hexists("person1-hash", "name"):
    data = json.loads(self.redisClient.hget('person1-hash').decode("utf-8"))
```

Unfortunately, it always turns out to be false. What am I missing?